# Is the Stack Overflow employee compensation calculator still available publicly?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

There [used to be](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507114000/https://stackoverflow.com/company/compensation/calculator) a compensation calculator hosted on Stack Overflow that was supposedly used to calculate salary internally for Stack Overflow employees ([previously a PDF](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues/114)):

[image]

The page last mentioned:

> This tool is no longer up-to-date. We will update it with more current information soon.

and then seemingly disappeared. I couldn't find any further information about it. Searching "compensation calculator" is overshadowed by results of the "Salary Calculator" pulled from the Developer Survey instead. Is the internal calculator still publicly available somewhere else?

Comment: it was probably retired with the talent product.

Comment: @KevinB The "Salary Calculator" based on the Developer Survey definitely was, but I am not asking about that. This is regarding the compensation calculator used for StackOverflow employees, which would have no relation to the Talent product.

Comment: It was retired when the network latency could not keep up with inflation:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, the internal salary calculator is no longer available.

However, our public job listings now include salary bands, which can help to give an idea about levels of compensation at the company.